# Python Opencv Mulithreading with RTSP feeds

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-capture, rtsp

I'm working on a small project for personal use where I want to load the CCTV streams I have from home into Opencv. I've done alot of research and understand that I need to use multithreading to get them to work correctly. and using the following code I've got it working on one camera perfectly!

```
from threading import Thread
import imutils
import cv2, time

camlink1 = "rtsp://xx.xx.xx.xx.:xxx/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=1&stream=0./"


class VideoStreamWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, link, camname, src=0):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(link)
        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()
        self.camname = camname
        self.link = link
        print(camname)
        print(link)

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()
            time.sleep(.01)

    def show_frame(self):

        # Display frames in main program
        frame = imutils.resize(self.frame, width=400)
        cv2.imshow('Frame ' + self.camname, frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_stream_widget = VideoStreamWidget(camlink1,"Cam1")

    while True:
        try:
            video_stream_widget.show_frame()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

But now I want run another camera alongside it (in parallel) but I'm not sure how what i need to change to the code to start another thread and run it side by side. I thought I did by using the following:

```
from threading import Thread
import imutils
import cv2, time

camlink1 = "rtsp://xx.xx.xx.xx.:xxx/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=1&stream=0./"
camlink2 = "rtsp://xx.xx.xx.xx.:xxx/user=xxx&password=xxx&channel=2&stream=0./"

class VideoStreamWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, link, camname, src=0):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(link)
        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()
        self.camname = camname
        self.link = link
        print(camname)
        print(link)

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()
            time.sleep(.01)

    def show_frame(self):

        # Display frames in main program
        frame = imutils.resize(self.frame, width=400)
        cv2.imshow('Frame ' + self.camname, frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_stream_widget = VideoStreamWidget(camlink1,"Cam1")
    video_stream_widget = VideoStreamWidget(camlink2,"Cam2")

    while True:
        try:
            video_stream_widget.show_frame()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

But this just shows the second camera only, overriding the first. I know somewhere I'm missing something simple but after looking at this for hours I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated

Cheers
Chris

Comment: Have you tried to put a different name to the variables, like `video_stream_widget` and `video_stream_widget2` and also to call show_frame of both of them? now you are replacing the one with cam1 with the one with cam2 and only calling show_frame on the one with cam2

Comment: So simple! Yeah I totally missed that - that fixed the issue! Thanks

Comment: No problem, I will write it as an answer for sake of completeness :)

Comment: Yeah, make sure you get the credit :)

Comment: I reckon you should read [this](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) before you start further to abuse the threading module of python. You should write your videostreaming apart from the threading application. If split this that you don't need to use the superficial patch from api55. Tip: start thinking server - client. Your main app is the server (threadpool for events with other main code to catch logs, errors, etc) and each cam is a client (a.k.a event).

Comment: @ZF007 I also think it is missing things, but since normally people do not post the entire code just a MVCE I normally just try to find the exact problem so the person can continue. Feel free to add another answer, this will help other people with a similar problem to not make the same mistakes :)

Comment: @api55 I really appreciate your help - I'm pretty new to this and am working my way through the PyImageSearch Guru course, I'm just trying things out along the way too. Cheers, Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in these lines of code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_stream_widget = VideoStreamWidget(camlink1,"Cam1")
    video_stream_widget = VideoStreamWidget(camlink2,"Cam2")

    while True:
        try:
            video_stream_widget.show_frame()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

To be precise, you are overwriting the the variable `video_stream_widget` and then calling once `video_stream_widget.show_frame()` This will be only call in the last one (even if the thread that captures the images is still working), so only the last one will be showing, i.e. "Cam2".

---

## Solution

Add different names for each and call the `show_frame()` function on both, like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_stream_widget = VideoStreamWidget(camlink1,"Cam1")
    video_stream_widget2 = VideoStreamWidget(camlink2,"Cam2")

    while True:
        try:
            video_stream_widget.show_frame()
            video_stream_widget2.show_frame()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Comment: superficial quick fix. OP is not learning how to use threading correctly.

Comment: Thanks ZF007 - yeah I definitely need to get into multi-threading more - and I'm starting to research now. Could you give me a bit more info into how you'd approach the above fix? It doesn't necessarily have to be code, just what you think would work better? Cheers, Chris